# Como montar dois sub selects sem union all

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria de obter um select de dois valores a partir de dois sub-selects em uma mesma consulta sem utilizar **union all**. Obtendo assim duas colunas uma com o valor max e min da id_questao

retorno com union all:

```
+-------+----+
| id_questao |
+------------+
|    122     |
|    125     |
+------------+
```

forma que quero obter o resultado:

```
+-------+-----+
| max |  min  |
+-----+-------+
| 122 |  125  |
+-------------+
```

estrutura da tabela:

```
+-------+----+---------------+
| id_questao | ordem_questao |
+------------+---------------+
|    120     |      2        |
|    122     |      4        |
|    123     |      3        |
|    125     |      1        |
+------------+---------------+
```

estrutura do select:

```
select id_questao from questao where ordem_questao = 
(select max(ordem_questao) from questao where id_campanha = 7) AND id_campanha = 7
    
select id_questao from questao where ordem_questao = 
(select min(ordem_questao) from questao where id_campanha = 7)  AND id_campanha = 7
```

Baseado no maximo e minimo da ordem_questao o retorno do id_questao seria:

max = 122 e o min = 125

Comment: select min(ordem_questao) min,max(ordem_questao) max from questao where id_campanha = 7 , creio ser isto.

Comment: Seria baseado na ordem_questao me traga o id_questao. Veja acima, fiz um complemento na pergunta @Motta

Comment: Entendi , o única saída que vejo agora seria uma sql de union como tabela virtual , fazendo um PIVOT (por CASE ou PIVOT) para exibir da forma que se quer.

Answer (score 0):

```
--DEVE TER ALGUMA FORMA MAIS SIMPLES 
--VEJA EM
--http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82779c1/2

CREATE TABLE QUESTAO (ID_QUESTAO INT,
                      ORDEM_QUESTAO INT,
                      ID_CAMPANHA INT);
                      
INSERT INTO QUESTAO VALUES (120,2,7);
INSERT INTO QUESTAO VALUES (122,4,7);
INSERT INTO QUESTAO VALUES (123,3,7);
INSERT INTO QUESTAO VALUES (125,1,7); 

INSERT INTO QUESTAO VALUES (220,2,8);
INSERT INTO QUESTAO VALUES (222,3,8);
INSERT INTO QUESTAO VALUES (223,4,8);
INSERT INTO QUESTAO VALUES (225,1,8); 

select max(case when tipo = 'max' then id_questao else null end) max,
       max(case when tipo = 'min' then id_questao else null end) min
from
(
select 'max' tipo,q1.id_questao id_questao
from questao q1
where q1.ordem_questao = (select max(ordem_questao) 
                          from questao q2
                          where q2.id_campanha = q1.id_campanha) 
AND q1.id_campanha = 7 
union all
select 'min' tipo,q1.id_questao id_questao
from questao q1
where q1.ordem_questao = (select min(ordem_questao) 
                          from questao q2
                          where q2.id_campanha = q1.id_campanha) 
AND q1.id_campanha = 7 
) qst
```

Comment: A forma que eu postei acima é mais simples... só adicionar o union all! Mas a questão seria não utilizar o union all. @Motta

Comment: Mas se queria o pivot também pelo que entendi. Mas a minha solução ficou complicada mesmo.